# Angular 2+ export specific table to excel

Tags: excel, angular

how can I export a [different](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cnrd0rsvo915apr/excell-armenian.xlsx?dl=0) column width table to excel like this image?

in this [example](https://medium.com/@madhavmahesh/exporting-an-excel-file-in-angular-927756ac9857) I can export only with equal columns.

[image]

Comment: How did the data get into Angular? Is it in some sort of array in your code where you can extract each piece? Most likely each of those individual data items will need to be separated out and placed into excel with the custom code you write.

Comment: I get data array from the server and do some calculates with them and set to table, and then to excel.

Comment: Then you would use that same logic you used to display it in Angular to place it into Excel. I do not think there is anything that will automatically copy and paste your custom formatting into Excel. But someone else may know of a way.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, but I need to find a way how to place my data into excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone who want like this excel, enjoy the solution.
[download-app-xlsx](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z16g0i6m3mzisw7/app-xlsx.zip?dl=0)